# Animations between activities hanging

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition, freeze

In my app, there are 2 activities. To make the transition seem smooth I animated elements of the first and second activity and disabled transition between the 2 activities. An example of what happens is in the video below:

https://youtu.be/L85HfIUPQuk

The problem as you might see is that, once the animations in the first activity end, there is a period, less than a second but still noticeable, where the screen hangs on the empty white background. Only after that does the second activity and animations start.

The animations are simple alpha and translate effects, nothing fancy.
Any suggestions how to get rid of the hanging period?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Activity Transition.
I think what you need is Shared Elements Transition, since the list from first screen is also on the second screen. Checkout the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html